# Protected route redirects before auth is finished

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

So basically I am trying to setup protected routes.

This is my **ProtectedRoute** component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import { authenticate } from './actions';

const ProtectedRoute = ({
  component: Component, authenticate, isAuthenticated, ...rest
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    authenticate();
  });

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => (isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      ))
      }
    />
  );
};

ProtectedRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  authenticate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { authenticate })(ProtectedRoute);
```

and here is the **authenticate** action:

```
const authenticate = () => dispatch => axios('http://localhost:8080/user', {
  method: 'get',
  withCredentials: true,
}).then((response) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'AUTHENTICATE_SUCCESS', payload: response.data });
}).catch((error) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'AUTHENTICATE_FAILURE' });
  throw (error);
});
```

But unfortunately it doesnt work because it redirects on render before the auth process has finished. What could I possibly do to solve this problem? Should I add an extra boolean to check if auth process is done before rendering anything? Or is there a better way?

Comment: What is the implementation of `authenticate`

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Added it to the question.

Comment: I think the best approach is to use `history` prop and instead of redirect inside the component, push the path to history in action in case of auth failure

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I did it that way but it renders the component for less than a second before redirecting.

Comment: so your authentication fails probably, what is the debug result in authentication function

Comment: No. It works properly but render runs before the auth process is finished. So the component is shown before it redirects.